# taking Image of HDD with reallocated bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, bad-sectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to copy files of HDD with bad sectors](https://superuser.com/questions/90799/tool-to-copy-files-of-hdd-with-bad-sectors)

My main hard disk has some bad sectors that have been reallocated. I haven't lost any files (from what I have seen) but it has become a little slow. If I take a disc image and restore it on a new hard drive... Will it work OK after or will it copy the bad sectors too and keep being slow?

If it is OK, which software is recommended? I have used Macrium Reflect in other PC.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend conventional imaging tools for cloning a drive that is already known to have bad sectors, it could have potential consequences.

Instead, I would use something like `dd_rescue` from the Linux command line to clone the partition (or drive) bit for bit. This tool will skip over bad sectors in the cloning process.  Assuming that there aren't too many bad sectors or errors you should be able to recover your data nearly completely.  It *shouldn't* screw any of the structure up since it is essentially making a mirror image of the drive.

The only other advice I can give is to be **extremely careful** when you clone the drive so you don't destroy any of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The "bad sectors" are hardware issues, not software ones.  Almost any imaging software will ignore those sectors because they are flagged by the OS as being unreadable.  The more important question is: if you have bad sectors, why do they exist, and how much longer do you have until total drive failure?

I've used DriveImageXML to create backup images of my drives in the past, but never for direct restoring like you are describing - just mirroring your old drive to new hardware. You'll need to use some kind of tool that clones the drive while it is not in use. If you use a Linux LiveCD, GParted can clone the partition between drives. The aformentioned dd_rescue is also a decent choice.

Before you undertake this, however, I would make sure your backups are in good order. Ultimately, the image may fail, and if it does, having good backups is the difference between having to reinstall your OS (but otherwise being okay) and having to recover the entirety of your life's data.